# Inheriting values from another struct

Tags: rust

I am trying to send jsons to the backend and would like to add an id and some meta to the structures before storing them. I am using Serde to deserialize the jsons to structs. Now the problem is adding fields to a structure the frontend is sending. As the structures have 20-30 fields I dont want to write them all out explicitly when inheriting the values.

```
struct Dentist {
    teeth: u8,
    smile: String
}

struct DentistMeta {
   id: u8,
   meta: String,
   teeth: u8,
   smile: String,
}

let dentist: Dentist = Dentist { teeth: 16, smile: "cute".to_string() };

// How to get this step done in Rust ??
let dentistMeta: DentistMeta = DentistMeta { id: 1, meta: "xyz".to_string(), dentist };
```

And I would rather not solve it like so:

```
struct DentistMeta {
   id: u8,
   meta: String,
   dentist: Dentist,
}
```

The only constraint is, after all is said and done, I need to be able to deserialize the jsons into a struct when retrieving them from the database.

Comment: "And I would rather not solve it like so" - could you describe in more detail, why this approach is not suitable in your case? Maybe there's an idiomatic workaround - for example, if the problem is only with deserializing, there's `serde::flatten` for this exact case.

Comment: Well when I store it like so I am basically embedding the relevant data in this meta wrapper which is something I would rather avoid because it adds more steps along the way when I need to retrieve the data.

Comment: I looked into flatten and it does make this process much smoother. If no other suggestions come up I am going with that! There was no mention of flatten at docs.rs or at serde json github and I didn't realize more documentation existed at serde.rs. So thank you for this! @Cerberus

Comment: Since Rust is not object-oriented, there is no concept of inheritance. Composition (the solution proposed by you and @Cerberus) is how you "share" or "inherit" structs in Rust. One benefit of composition over inheritance is that you can do something like this: `struct Meta<T> { id: u8, meta: String, value: T }`. This would be very useful if you have multiple structures that you want to serialize with metadata.

Comment: What you are looking for is Golang struct embedding. This is currently not possible in Rust (unless you create a macro). This is an idea that has been floating around. There is an [open rfc here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2431)